# Manually trigger validations(Validate Formik Form ) on button click even when fields are untouched

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks, formik, yup, higher-order-components

In our React app, We have multiple forms in a page. We use Formik and Yup for forms and validations respectively

Currently validations are fired only when field/form are touched. We have build wrapper on Formik that submits form on blur/focus out event.

Now, the requirement is to show error for all the required fields in  a page that includes multiple Formik forms on click of a button.

To clarify further, my wrapper looks like

```
    const { onSubmit, className, style, ...restProps } = this.props;
    return (
        <div
            ref={this.setContainerRef}
            onBlur={this.handleBlur}
            onFocus={this.handleFocus}
            tabIndex={-1}
            className={className}
            style={style}
        >
            <Formik
                {...restProps}
                ref={this.setFormikRef}
                initialValues={this.props.currentValues}
                validateOnBlur={true}
                validateOnChange={false}
                render={(formikProps: FormikProps<T>) => (
                    <>
                        <DirtyFormReporter onChange={this.handleDirtyFormReport} isDirty={formikProps.dirty} />
                        {this.props.render(formikProps, this.createEditBlurFormActions())}
                    </>
                )}
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            />
            {ReactDOM.createPortal(<InputBlocker text="Updating" isEnabled={this.state.isSubmitting} />, document.body)}
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score -2):

There are multiple ways to handle this situation but you can use **fieldarray of Formik** here.

```
https://formik.org/docs/api/fieldarray
```

When you will submit you will get an array and a list of forms in it then you can simple add and remove forms and you can easily do your validation using Yup.

Comment: If you see the validation part of it, you will see :
Validation can be tricky with <FieldArray>.

If you use validationSchema and your form has array validation requirements (like a min length) as well as nested array field requirements, displaying errors can be tricky. Formik/Yup will show validation errors inside out.
That is already in working condition and I do not certainly want to touch that part